# CORS - Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send a GET request to a server (the server and the local host have the same domain), however I keep getting the following error:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

This is the code I use to send the request

```
$.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*",
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token"
            }
        });
            $.get(myurl, function(data) {

                console.log(data);
            });
```

I not sure how to fix this error, since I'm new to web development.

Comment: You need to set these headers on API endpoint, the URL you are hitting  means `myurl` not in your ajax request.

Comment: Hi, Keselme, were the answers under this question helpful? It is customary to mark one answer as accepted if it answered your question. You can find [more details in Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present **on the requested resource**.

The Access-Control control headers have to be sent by the responding server. Depending on the response and requesting page, browser may allow the request to proceed, out just show the error you got.

If adding the headers was enough, any CORS policy would be moot: any page could access any resource.

> the server and the local host have the same domain

I'm not sure what you mean here, but apparently your page is loaded from a different domain than `myurl` points to.

Answer (score 1):

The Access-Control headers should be sent by the server, not by the client.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set Access-Control in your server app, If your back-end is on java then you can use filter to set Access-Control headers